# How to get the Error Code of CDO.Message

Tags: delphi, error-handling, certificate, transport, cdo.message

I wrote my routines for using CDO.Message. It's working long time ago.
But now, in some site they installed a certificate and then the priorly working version is making errors with all calls.

I used simple variants to hold the CDO.Message COM object.

When I used Send method(?) it returns a HResult.
But it's interesting, because the HResult is unusable for get the error code, because the Send is seems to be a real method which makes Exception on problems.
So the result code is -1 if I set to this value before.

I tried to get the last error code with GetLastError. But this is 0.

I can catch the Exception, but it contains only the error message what is:

"The transport failed to connect to the server"

The VB codes can get the error code which could provide extra information about the problem (or not).

Do you know about a technic to get the error code value from Delphi XE3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be better if we had some source code at hand. Specifically the Delphi declaration of the COM interface.

My guess is that the method is declared as `safecall`. What this means is that the compiler understands that the method is actually `stdcall` returning `HRESULT`, and re-writes the parameters to match. If the true COM method returns an `HRESULT` other than `S_OK` then the compiler writes code to check for that and convert the error into an exception.

The exception that is raised will be `EOleSysError` and that has the property `ErrorCode` which contains the `HRESULT` that you are looking for.

So, you need to:

- Add an exception handler to catch `EOleSysError`.
- Read the `ErrorCode` property of the `EOleSysError` exception instance that you catch.

This is all a little bit round the houses. If you'd prefer to avoid exception handling, then you can always re-write the COM interface declaration to be a true `stdcall` method returning an `HRESULT`.